# Oracle Apex 21.1: how to's require for create, store and retrieve (authenticate) users with hashed passwords

Tags: security, hash, apex

i am using Oracle Apex 21.1 and want to **implement hashed passwords for users** (public page like an eCommerce website). How i can implement to have this feature in my Oracle Apex applicaation? if there is any step by step approach tutorial for beginners, please share the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE
   input_string       VARCHAR2 (200) :=  'Secret Message';
   output_string      VARCHAR2 (200);
   encrypted_raw      RAW (2000);             -- stores encrypted binary text
   decrypted_raw      RAW (2000);             -- stores decrypted binary text
   num_key_bytes      NUMBER := 256/8;        -- key length 256 bits (32 bytes)
   key_bytes_raw      RAW (32);               -- stores 256-bit encryption key
   encryption_type    PLS_INTEGER :=          -- total encryption type
                            DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT_AES256
                          + DBMS_CRYPTO.CHAIN_CBC
                          + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_PKCS5;
   iv_raw             RAW (16);

BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'Original string: ' || input_string);
   key_bytes_raw := DBMS_CRYPTO.RANDOMBYTES (num_key_bytes);
   iv_raw        := DBMS_CRYPTO.RANDOMBYTES (16);
   encrypted_raw := DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT
      (
         src => UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW (input_string,  'AL32UTF8'),
         typ => encryption_type,
         key => key_bytes_raw,
         iv  => iv_raw
      );
    -- The encrypted value "encrypted_raw" can be used here

   decrypted_raw := DBMS_CRYPTO.DECRYPT
      (
         src => encrypted_raw,
         typ => encryption_type,
         key => key_bytes_raw,
         iv  => iv_raw
      );
   output_string := UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR (decrypted_raw, 'AL32UTF8');
 
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Decrypted string: ' || output_string); 
 
END;
```

Comment: thanks @Enrique Flores for response. i run the code as is but sqlplus throws error "ERROR at line 9:
ORA-06550: line 9, column 29:
PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_CRYPTO' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 0, column 0:
PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated"  oracle DB version currently am using is 21cXE.

Comment: ok, its already installed and needs to grant from SYS to a database user to access it. just one question, are these types of hashed passwords can be decrypt after some time period ? i tried created a function, access it as select get_pwd('mywife', 'enc') from dual; it executes and show me the encrypted mywife but when try to descrypt that output it shows like-wise value instead of 'mywife' i think i lost mywife... is it not possible? or i am  missing something? please guide. regards